# How can i place the Label inside CollectionView so that nearest Cell affects the "Y" position of the Label?

Tags: ios, tvos, tvos9.1, focus-engine

How can i place the Label inside CollectionView so that nearest cell also affects the "Y" position of the Label ? https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/images/visual-design-animation.mp4

So the idea is, when you have Cell in focus that is **near your UILabel**, your UILabel change its "Y" position by +/- 20 points for example.
I know that i have callback **didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)**, but i cant get UILabel center.y to change if **Cell that is near** in focus.

I have nested Collections. Main CollectionView have vertical scrollDirection and Cells that holds inside another Collections with horizontal scrollDirection.

[image: cell that need to bring label UP]

Any help would be appreciated )
Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Section header for that purpose.
or 
you can calculate cell spacing according to the label.

Comment: how actually UICollectionReusableView take part in bouncing UILabels on top of Cells ?

Answer (score 0):

A behaviour that you described in this question is a standard behaviour for the TVML-item called `shelf` with a `header` label. I think that you need to use a hybrid application, you should replace your current page with a TVML page (it will looks more pretty than you planned to implement with the `UICollectionView`).